# Incremental z-index in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a navigation bar and I need to always keep the current one on top. I came up with this code, but I don't know why it's not working:

```
$(this).find('ul.sub_nav').css('z-index', function(index) {
     return index++;
});
```

I inspect it in chrome and all it shows is `<ul class="sub_nav" style="z-index: 0;">` no matter how many times I try it.

It has an initial `z-index` of 1, just FYI.

---

What I resolved:

```
var zIndex = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.top_nav > li').hover(function() {
        zIndex++;
        $(this).find('ul.sub_nav').css('z-index', zIndex);
    });
});
```

A much simpler solution with JS.

Comment: Please show us your HTML.  It's hard to understand what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should do this instead, if you want each element to have a `zIndex` greater than previous elements in a specific set.

```
var subs  = $(this).find('ul.sub_nav');
var index = subs.eq(0).css('z-index');
subs.gt(0).each(function() {
    $(this).css('z-index', ++index);
});
```

Comment: I realized that a minute ago. The `z-index` needs to increment off of the `ul` with the highest `z-index`. Thanks. I managed to make a simpler sintax with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the z-index using css instead of using jquery and js.  Also if your using z-index make sure the position of the element is set to relative.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index

If you cannot just set the css try:

```
$(this).find('ul.sub_nav').css('z-index', function(index, value) {
     return value++;
});
```

Comment: Because it needs to be dynamic, I assume.

Comment: So other elements are changing their z-index and you need to keep this one on top?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `function(index)`, maybe try `function(i, index)`.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't know what it is for, but instead of the `z-index` being 0, it's now 1. but it still doesn't increment.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  Read the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/).  It's `function(index, i)` where `index` is the position of this object in the jQuery object and `i` is the old value of the CSS, nor does it help solve anything.

Comment: Yes it does. If the asker put the `i` before the `index`, then `index` would be the 2nd parameter to the function, which would make it correspond with the z-index.

Comment: Then, give the parameter a meaningful name (like `currentVal`) so someone reading the code has a clue what you're trying to do.  This is obscure code.  The jQuery doc doesn't lead you in a helpful direction with the parameter names, but that doesn't mean you have to follow that obscure path.  I could not tell what you were trying to do from your answer because of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one navbar of several to be visible, it's much easier to `.hide()` all the navbars and `.show()` the one you want to see.

```
$('ul.sub_nav').not('.current').hide();
$('ul.sub_nav.current').show();
```

We could be more precise about what to recommend if you included your actual HTML and told us more about what you're really trying to accomplish.

In the code example from your question, what this JS:

```
$(this).find('ul.sub_nav').css('z-index', function(index) {
     return index++;
});
```

does is set the z-index to a value that corresponds to the position each object has in the .find() jQuery object.  So, for the first object in the `$(this).find('ul.sub_nav')` object, the `index` argument will be zero and you will set the z-index to 0.  For the second object in the set it will be set to 1 and so on.

If you want just one particular navbar to be visible, why don't you just show that one and hide the others.  That's way less complicated than managing a z-index on all of them.

Also, are these navbars `position: absolute`?  If they are `position: static` (the default), then `z-index` won't affect them.

Answer (score 0):

You variable index isn't being incremented.  It's outside the scope of your loop.  I would try something like this.

```
$(this).find('ul.sub_nav').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('z- index', i+1)} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do something like
`$(yourelement).on("mouseover",function(){ $(this).css("z-index", "+=1") });` 
.. just make sure you have set an inital z-index e.g. in css

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done:    add an html span to your footer or anywhere apart from head section

```
<span class='current-index' style='display: none;'>1</span>
```

then in your jquery click event you can do this

```
$('.a_link_or_button').click(function(){
//get the current z-index value    
   var currentIndex=$('.current-index').text();
   $('.anotherDiv').show().css('z-index', currentIndex');

   //update the span which holds the current index with new z-index    

   var newCurrentIndex=parseInt(currentIndex)+1;

   $('.curent-index').text(newCurrentIndex);
```

Hope it helps someone out there. Note: instead of click function you can use hover func